# Data not binding in DataTable on pagination when using ajax to populate dataTable

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I am using a Data table to display a Document list. Where we can add new documents also. I am binding data to DataTable using Ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: path,
            data: { Id: "0", MId: $("#MId").val() },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

                var result = response.map(function (item) {
                    var result = [];

                    result.push(item.Id);
                    result.push(item.DocumentName);
                    result.push(item.Description);
                    result.push(item.UploadedOn);
                    result.push(item.UploadedBy);
                    result.push(item.UploadedDocument);
                    result.push(item.MId);

                    return result;
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    result[i][0] = "<span id='" + result[i][0] + "'>" + result[i][1] + "</span>";
                    result[i][1] = "<span>" + result[i][2] + "</span>";
                    result[i][2] = "<span>" + result[i][3] + "</span>";
                    result[i][3] = "<span>" + result[i][4] + "</span>";
                    result[i][4] = "<a href='" xxxxxxxx"</a>";
                    result[i][5] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"</i></label>";
                   t.row.add(result[i]);

                }

                $("#user-detail-datatable").DataTable().draw();

                $("#user-detail-datatable").DataTable().clear();
            },
            error: function (error) {

            }
        });
```

It is working perfect  if number of document is less than 10 but if it is more then onclick of the next button(pagination). It shows no data to display. and I am also unable to go back to the 1st page also.How to solve this issue . I am using bootstrap datatable.

TIA

Comment: I wolud request you to give js fiddle link of  working code ?

Comment: how are you triggering this ajax?

Comment: On document.ready I am calling this function and also after saving new documents

Comment: if its on document ready why are you using ajax?

Comment: I have to bind the data table  I am getting data using ajax call

Comment: On clicking next button I am not able to get datas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `clear()` before adding new rows.

```
success: function (response) {
   $("#user-detail-datatable").DataTable().clear()

   // Add new rows

   $("#user-detail-datatable").DataTable().draw();
}
```

Comment: but on clicking the next button I am not calling the bind function